# Analyse format of alpha-numeric string

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a string, parses it, and returns another string that summarizes the number of consecutive alpha or numeric characters in the original string.

For example, the string `999aa45bbx` would return `3N2A2N3A`, 
i.e.

- 3 numbers,
- followed by 2 alpha,
- by 2 numbers,
- by 3 alpha.

I'm using the function to analyze formats of insurance policy ID numbers. So far, I've found solutions online that extract either alpha or numeric characters, but nothing that describes the format or order in which these characters exist in the original string.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Seems like you could just loop through the string one character at a time, checking whether the character is numeric or alpha, and keep count.  Have you tried something like that?  If yes, it would help to post what you have, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A regexp like this will do the job

- press [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)[f11](/questions/tagged/f11) together to go the VBE
- Insert Module
- copy and paste the code below
- press [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)[f11](/questions/tagged/f11) together to go back to Excel

then you can use the function (which also detects invalid strings) within Excel, ie in B1
`=AlphaNumeric(A1)`

[image]

```
Function AlphaNumeric(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim objRegMC As Object
    Dim objRegM As Object
    Dim strOut As String
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "[^\w]"
        If .test(strIn) Then
            AlphaNumeric = "One or more characters is invalid"
        Else
            .Pattern = "(\d+|[a-z]+)"
            Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
            For Each objRegM In objRegMC
                strOut = strOut & (objRegM.Length & IIf(IsNumeric(objRegM), "N", "A"))
            Next
            AlphaNumeric = strOut
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Old school, looping through all characters in the string:

```
Function IdentifyCharacterSequences(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim charCounter As Long
    Dim currentCharType As String
    Dim sOut As String

    sOut = ""
    charCounter = 1
    currentCharType = CharType(Mid(s, 1, 1))

    For i = 2 To Len(s)
        If (Not CharType(Mid(s, i, 1)) = currentCharType) Or (i = Len(s)) Then
            sOut = sOut & charCounter & currentCharType
            currentCharType = CharType(Mid(s, i, 1))
            charCounter = 1
        Else
            charCounter = charCounter + 1
        End If
    Next i

    IdentifyCharacterSequences = sOut
End Function
```

This uses the following helper function. Note that non-alphanumeric characters are identified using the letter "X". You can easily modify this to suit your purposes.

```
Function CharType(s As String) As String
    If s Like "[A-z]" Then
        CharType = "A"
    ElseIf s Like "[0-9]" Then
        CharType = "N"
    Else
        CharType = "X"
        'Or raise an error if non-alphanumerical chars are unacceptable.
    End If
End Function
```

Usage example:

[image]