# Excel - Counting letters and numbers separately in a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need a way to count numbers and letters separately within one cell.

For example, if a cell contains `1234567ABC` I need to be able to output this as

- "7 Numbers" and
- "3 Letters".

I can't think of a way to use the `len()` function that would work, and `countif` only counts the cells themselves.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Heh, Excel. Have you tried using a macro?

Comment: Would that not still require me to know the code to count the individual numbers and letters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If each cell is filled only with numbers and letters, a quick non-vba way to accomplish this is to nest a substitute function 10 times to remove the 10 numerical characters. what you're left with is alpha only. Then you can `len()` the alpha text / subtract that number from the original length to get the numerical length.

Assuming "1234567ABC" is in cell A1:

This formula gives the number of letters. (3)

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""),1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,""))
```

This formula gives the total numbers: (7)

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""),1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,""))
```

If you want to start handling the data in other ways / any more in depth, a VBA solution will likely be required.

**Note**

To meet requirements in your original post, add this suffix to the end of the above formulas:

```
=x & " Numbers / Letters"
```

Where x = the above two formulas. this will add the text after the calculated number.

**Further Reading:**

The following link details a VBA UDF that does something similar: 
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/16364-how-remove-numbers.html

**Additional Update** (thanks lori_m)

This formula is a LOT easier to read / update:

```
=SUM(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},"")))
```

Comment: It works in Excel 2007 onwards but that would overrun the eight nested function restriction in prior versions. An alternative for the total numbers is: `=SUM(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},"")))`

Comment: Ah!!! I tried the  {} with substitute and it didn't work, i forgot to sum it! (i've been way too busy today at work) i'll add this as an update.  Thanks lori.

Answer (score 3):

From my answer in [Analyse format of alpha-numeric string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081492/vba-function-to-analyze-format-of-alpha-numeric-string/10082533#10082533):

For a more detailed answer this string 
`1234567ABC456`
would be reported as
`7N3L3N`

A regexp like this will do the job

- press [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)[f11](/questions/tagged/f11) together to go the VBE
- Insert Module
- copy and paste the code below
- press [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)[f11](/questions/tagged/f11) together to go back to Excel

then you can use the function (which also detects invalid strings) within Excel, ie in B1
`=AlphaNumeric(A1)`

[image]

```
Function AlphaNumeric(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim objRegMC As Object
    Dim objRegM As Object
    Dim strOut As String
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "[^\w]"
        If .test(strIn) Then
            AlphaNumeric = "One or more characters is invalid"
        Else
            .Pattern = "(\d+|[a-z]+)"
            Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
            For Each objRegM In objRegMC
                strOut = strOut & (objRegM.Length & IIf(IsNumeric(objRegM), "N", "L"))
            Next
            AlphaNumeric = strOut
        End If
    End With
End Function
```